Spring boot Redis omit phantoms during search
I am using Redis search together with Spring data redis.
I need time to live functionality hence phantoms are created by the framework which is fine.
But when doing ft.search I do not want those phantoms to be returned.
127.0.0.1:6379> ft.search list_idx '@attr1 { 12345 }' nocontent sortby name limit 0 2
1) (integer) 20
2) "gqlsearchcache:cf32744180f6"
3) "gqlsearchcache:f32744180f6:phantom"

I should not have phantoms when searching the indices.
Is there any option to do tjat?
I was trying to turn off creating shadows in spring boot but I need the phantoms for the business logic.
